# ensureRequiredPrimaryTypesLoaded throwing NullPointerException on first access under Jetty

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jcr, modeshape

I am working on a "resource" controller using the latest Spring3 and JBoss Modeshape (pointing to a federated repository using the Filesystem connectors) to retrieve an asset.

When I access any webpage, using the controller, it returns *most* of the images then throws a NullPointerException in the "getNode" call at various other ones...

**On my end, I am not doing anything special (my test cases work fine):**

1. Create/configure the engine (only once)
2. Login and get a session
3. Try to find the node
4. Logout from the session

**The code pretty much looks like:**

```
session = createSession();
Node node = session.getNode(path);
```

After the first hit to the page (with errors), every hit after that works perfect and everything loads fine from then out.

I am following this link [Heavy Concurrency: A better way to manage JCR Sessions](http://whiteboardjunkie.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/heavy-concurrency-a-better-way-to-manage-jcr-sessions) for the session creation/management.

It appears as if I have multiple threads trying to configure the JcrNodeDefinition in Modeshape. If i mark the `enureRequirePrimaryTypesLoaded()` method as `synchronized` then I do not get the error ever.

Anyone have any experience/suggestions with using Modeshape, concurrency, and session management?

**The stack trace is:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrNodeDefinition.ensureRequiredPrimaryTypesLoaded(JcrNodeDefinition.java:114)
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrNodeDefinition.allowsChildWithType(JcrNodeDefinition.java:275)
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.RepositoryNodeTypeManager.findChildNodeDefinition(RepositoryNodeTypeManager.java:1142)
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.JcrNodeTypeManager.findChildNodeDefinition(JcrNodeTypeManager.java:433)
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.SessionCache$JcrNodeOperations.materialize(SessionCache.java:2711)
>       at org.modeshape.graph.session.GraphSession$Node.load(GraphSession.java:1755)
>       at org.modeshape.graph.session.GraphSession$Node.getPayload(GraphSession.java:3030)
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.AbstractJcrNode.getNode(AbstractJcrNode.java:950)
>       at org.modeshape.jcr.AbstractJcrNode.getNode(AbstractJcrNode.java:96)
>       at com.acme.beans.contents.FileNodeAdapter.(FileNodeAdapter.java:26)
>       at com.acme.web.views.ResourceController.getStream(ResourceController.java:77)
>       at com.acme.web.views.ResourceController.handleResource(ResourceController.java:46)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend posting this on the [ModeShape discussion forums](https://community.jboss.org/community/modeshape?view=discussions) and, in this case, logging an issue so the development team can evaluate it. Those are the best ways to directly communicate with ModeShape users and ask about ModeShape-specific problems or questions.